# ScalaTest - JUnitRunner cannot be found

Tags: scala, junit, scalatest

I am trying to run my tests with the annoatqaion as per ScalaTest website:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.hamcrest.Matchers._
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert._
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import scala.Predef.String


@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
```

I am getting the following error messages when I try to build:

```
    error: not found: object classOf
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])

error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: <error: <none>>[JUnitRunner]
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
```

If I remove the annotation the tests run as well, but I presume the point of the annotation is to allow better running environment from JUnit... ANy help would be greatly appreaciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this import to make it work:

```
import scala.Predef.String
```

All members of `Predef` are automatically imported for you by the compiler, unless you import a selective one manually like this. `classOf` is a member of `Predef` and gets hidden this way.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
        <artifactId>specs2-junit_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```